# How to Make _ _ LINE _ _ and _ _ FILE_ _ run in perl?

Tags: windows, perl, literals, console2

(The Script)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Program, named literals.perl
```

written to test special literals

```
1   print "We are on line number ", _ _LINE_ _, ".\n";
2   print "The name of this file is ",_ _FILE_ _,".\n";
3   _ _END_ _
```

And this stuff is just a bunch of chitter–chatter that is to be
ignored by Perl. The `_ _END_ _ literal` is like `Ctrl–d` or `\004.[a]`

(Output)

> 1   We are on line number 3.
>   2   The name of this file is literals.perl.

Explanation
The special literal `_ _LINE_ _` cannot be enclosed in quotes if it is to be interpreted. It holds the current line number of the Perl script.

The name of this script is **literals.perl**. The special literal `_ _FILE_ _` holds the name of the current Perl script.

The special literal `_ _END_ _` represents the logical end of the script. It tells Perl to ignore any characters that follow it.

```
print "The script is called", _ _FILE_ _, "and we are on line number ",
_ _LINE_ _,"\n";
```

(Output)

> The script is called ./testing.plx and we are on line number 2

I need help getting this example to work. I am having a bit of trouble running it. when i run it on console2 i would get an error stating this

> "cant locate object method "_" via package "*LINE*" (perhaps you
>   forgot to load "*LINE*"?) at C:\users\john\desktop\console2\test.pl
>   line 5.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Learn how to use the code formatting tool on Stack Overflow, because we can't tell what program you're running.  Paste the literal code, highlight it, and click the `{}` icon to indent it 4 spaces.

Comment: The names, if they work at all, will be `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` with double underscores and no spaces, just like the symbols used in C with the C preprocessor.  The error message suggests that you used `_ _FILE_ _` with spaces and not just because the Markdown editor in Stack Overflow treats `__` as a symbol for bold.  What gives?  Can you quote the exact error message?  I'm pretty sure it doesn't use "cant" instead of "can't" with an apostrophe.  And it should be indented 4 spaces so it appears as 'code'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use names without spaces between the underscores:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "We are on line number ", __LINE__, ".\n";
print "The name of this file is ", __FILE__, ".\n";
__END__

print "This is not part of the script\n";
```

When saved in `fileline.pl` and run, this produces:

```
We are on line number 5.
The name of this file is fileline.pl.
```

Note that there are no spaces between the consecutive underscores.  And note that the final line containing a `print` statement is not part of the script because it comes after the `__END__`.  (There's also a `__DATA__` directive that can sometimes be useful.)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! I was able to get it working i removed the spaces between the literals. I greatly appreciate it. Btw, why does the perl example uses _ _FILE_ _, _ _LINE _ _ etc when it should instead use __FILE__,__LINE__ ?

Comment: Where did you get the Perl example?

Comment: @JawnFam: Some people have problems spotting the difference between `_FILE_` and `__FILE__` so they use a space (preferably a fractional space, such as U+2009 THIN SPACE or U+200A HAIR SPACE) to separate them, but of course such spaces don't work well in a constant-width font.  Also, on SO, the Markdown system treats double underscores as a bold marker and single underscores requesting italic: __FILE__ and _FILE_.  Contrast _ _ FILE _ _ which should be just visible as two separate underscores with minimal space around them (U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE).

Comment: @JimDavis i am using a book called "perl by example" its written by ellie quigley fourth edition. I am a noob, so i asked one of my coworkers who happens to be a programmer on which language i should learn first and he recommended perl, so i stuck with it. Imma try and finish the book and move on to another language one im done.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okie dokie, i understand now. thank you for the clarification.

Comment: "Perl By Example" is a terrible book. You would be much better advised to read "Learning Perl" or "Beginning Perl".

Answer (score 2):

There's no space in the literals `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` (or `__END__`).  Just 2 underscores in a row, the word, and another 2 underscores.